# Is there a way to run an app from SD and bind it to the card?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sdcard, sd-card

Is it possible to run an app from an SD card instead of from the device? It would be an internal app, not public, and would be work only with the chip were it was builder. Is it possible?  Any advice? If yes, any tips to how develop it?

Comment: It's up to the apps developer.  If they don't block it, yes you can run it from the SD card.

Comment: I agree, but what I'm looking is some tip to the developper side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that dex code can be run from anywhere, and editing mainfest I can force to install the app on the sd.